# Tomcat war file deployment fails

Tags: tomcat, deployment

When I am deploying my web app in tomcat by going to webapps it is being deployed and status is also showing true but when I am deploying same app by creating war file using console deployment its failing by giving an error.
And also not showing in applications list

FAIL - War file already exists on server....

Comment: You need to undeploy that running application in the application console and upload it.

Comment: It's showing there in deployed applications list...

Comment: If it is already running you need to undeploy or stop in application console. After doing any step deploy it from application console.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before, but, for me, the app was not listed in the applications list in Tomcat Web Application Manager.  I had to open a terminal and delete the directory and war file from the webapps directory.  For me the webapps was at /var/lib/tomcat/webapps.

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was code compilation error
x.y.z Class not found Exception

Please check the tomcat logs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).